# AWS SAM Model fails while creating API with Custom domain name using cross account hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

Problem Statement

My R53 Domain name and Hosted zone is in Account A. I want to create an API in Account B (Thru SAM Model) which will have a custom domain name declared in Account A.

Here is my sample SAM Template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Domain:
        CertificateArn: pCertificateArn
        BasePath:
          - pVersion
        DomainName: pCustomDomainName
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: pHostedZoneId
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      StageName: pStageName
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri:
      Handler: hello.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        AuthApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello-main
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
```

Im executing this SAM template via a Pipeline, here is the code for the deploy role of the pipeline. This will be executed in Account B

```
 rDeployProjectRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-DEPLOYPROJECT-ROLE-${pEnv}'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: 
              - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-DEPLOYPROJECT-POLICY-${pEnv}'
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
<highlighting only the necessary assumed role>
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
              Resource: !Ref pRoute53AssumedRoleArn
```

Now in my Account A, i have created a role to give access to the Account B like this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  CreateRoute53Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::<Account B>:root
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: Route53Access
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - route53:*
              Resource: 
                - arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/XXX
```

Everytime i run the above code, it fails with this error in the cfn stack -

```
API: route53:GetHostedZone User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/XXX-DEPLOYPROJECT-ROLE-dev/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to access this resource
```

Interesting when i look up the role (XXX-DEPLOYPROJECT-ROLE-dev) in IAM and look at the access advisor, it says that my *pRoute53AssumedRoleArn* is not even accessed. Im not sure what im doing wrong.

Also, if i were to create my API through the SAM template in Account A, it gets created perfectly fine, with the custom domain name, just the way i want it.

It seems problematic only with the cross account domain name access.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was posted a while back but maybe this will be a little bit helpful as it does not quite do what the original poster wanted.

My work around was to delegate a domain from route53 in account A to the account with my api (Account B).  This basically allows my to set the whole thing up in account B and avoid trying to get all the permissions set up correctly to get this working across accounts.  A nice side effect to this setup is that in means that I don not give permission to account B access to make changes in my main DNS setup in account A.

Instructions to delegate a subdomain are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html

This post describes how to basically automate the process (which is way, way more than I need for my project) but may help you if you need this functionality on a large scale: https://hitthecloudrunning.com/blog/2020/04/12/managing-cross-account-dns-with-route-53-lambda-and-cloudformation/

Comment: I was trying to set up a SAM application that runs in a multi-account setup that is managed with Terraform.  This subdomain solution provides a great way of drawing a line between the Terraform managed Domains (Account A) and SAM domains (Account B... C, D, etc...).